# How to groupby and collpase with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the following type:

```
    Country     Year    Age     Male    Female
0   Canada      2005    50       400      25
1   Canada      2005    51       100      25
2   Canada      2006    50       100      70
3   Columbia    2005    50       75       75
```

I would like to, for example, get the total number of males+females of any age, grouped by country and year. I.e. I'm trying to understand what operation could allow me to see a table such as

```
    Country     Year    Total over ages and sexes
0   Canada      2005    550
1   Canada      2006    170
2   Columbia    2005    150
```

In the above example, the value 550 comes from the total number of males and females in Canada for the year 2005, regardless of age: so 550 = 400+25+100+25.

I probably need to `groupby` Country and Year, but I'm not sure how to collapse the ages and total the number of males and females.

Comment: Can you please be a little more clear with what you mean by "collapse"? How do you end up with those numbers? Please break down the calculations, it would help.

Comment: I've expanded on the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["Total"] = df.Male + df.Female
df.groupby(["Country", "Year"]).Total.sum()
```

Output:

```
Country   Year
Canada    2005    550
          2006    170
Columbia  2005    150
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```

**Update**
cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's chained version:

```
(df.assign(Total=df.Male + df.Female)
   .groupby(['Country', 'Year'])
   .Total
   .sum()
   .reset_index(name='Total over ages and sexes'))
```

Comment: `df.assign(Total=df.Male + df.Female).groupby(['Country', 'Year']).Total.sum().reset_index(name='Total over ages and sexes')`